# MySql InnoDB Select Query takes more time to result data

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-performance

I have a MySQL InnoDB table which uses per day table structure (a single table to store per day data). Each table consist of 50 columns (this table cannot be normalized since this table is used to store CDR data (telco related) having around 16 million rows per table.

This is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <tableName_2018_07_08> ( 
 <col1> int(4) NOT NULL,
 <col2> timestamp NOT NULL,
 <col3> varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 <col4> int(4) NOT NULL,
 <col5> varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 <col6> varchar(255),
 <col7> varchar(255),
 <col8> varchar(255),
 <col9> varchar(255),
 <col10> varchar(255),
 <col11> varchar(255),
 <col12> varchar(255),
 <col13> varchar(255),
 <col14> varchar(255),
 <col15> varchar(255),
 <col16> varchar(255),
 <col17> varchar(255),
 <col18> varchar(255),
 <col19> varchar(255),
 <col20> varchar(255),
 <col21> varchar(255),
 <col22> varchar(255),
 <col23> varchar(255),
 <col24> varchar(255),
 <col25> varchar(255),
 <col26> varchar(255),
 <col27> varchar(255),
 <col28> varchar(255),
 <col29> varchar(255),
 <col30> varchar(255),
 <col31> varchar(255),
 <col32> varchar(255),
 <col33> varchar(255),
 <col34> varchar(255),
 <col35> varchar(255),
 <col36> varchar(255),
 <col37> varchar(255),
 <col38> varchar(255),
 <col39> varchar(255),
 <col40> varchar(255),
 <col41> varchar(255),
 <col42> varchar(255),
 <col43> varchar(255),
 <col44> varchar(255),
 <col45> varchar(255),
 <col46> varchar(255),
 <col47> varchar(255),
 <col48> varchar(255),
 <col49> varchar(255),
 <col50> varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (<col1>, <col2>, <col3>, <col4>, <col5>)
) ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

There are 4 fields which is used in the where clause of the query.

```
select 
    cast(<col1> as char),
    <col2>,
    <col3>,
    cast(<col4> as char),
    <col5>,
    <col6>,
    <col6>,
    <col7>,
    <col8>,
    <col9>,
    <col10>,
    <col11>,
    <col12>,
    <col13>,
    <col14>,
    <col15>,
    <col16>,
    <col16>,
    <col17>,
    <col18>,
    <col19>,
    <col20>,
    <col21>,
    <col22>,
    <col23>,
    <col24>,
    <col25>,
    <col26>,
    <col27>,
    <col28>,
    <col29>,
    <col30>,
    <col31>,
    <col32>,
    <col33>,
    <col34>,
    <col35>,
    <col36>,
    <col37>,
    <col38>,
    <col39>,
    <col40>
FROM 
    <tabele_2018_03_03> 
WHERE 
    col2 >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00' AND 
    col2 <= '2018-07-01 02:00:00' AND
    col3 = 'Test01' AND col4 = '11'
```

The from time and to time is sent from the front-end and also there are three more filters which are added only if those filters are sent from the front-end.

This query takes more than 5 minutes to result which is a problem. Since this is only for single day and whenever the front end sends to fetch the data for multiple days it will take more than 10 minutes.

Comment: I'm confused your header says innodb your create says memory.

Comment: You do not have indexes that could be used to speed up the query filtering on `cdr_timestamp` only.

Comment: @P.Salmon : Sorry the MEMORY engine create statement was a mistake. It is InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

MEMORY?  Or Innodb?  MEMORY is volatile; don't use MEMORY except for staging.

Table per day -- Usually a bad design.

"More filters added" -- Let's see them.  Any solution for the query you provided may not help for other situations.

You want 2 hours plus 1 second?  Check the range test.

`cast(event as char)` -- unnecessary; the output is indistinguishable from a string, even without the `cast`.

Without an index *starting* with `cdr_timestamp`, that query will have to search the entire table.  Adding an index *may not* help since the query is looking at perhaps 2/24ths of the table.

Normalization *can* and *should* be applied.  Sure, the data comes in as strings, but you should convert more of the columns before storing in the 'Fact' table. 
 It will take an extra step or two.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

That link provides several tips that would help you -- You are inserting about 200 rows per second, close to the limit without taking extra steps; that gives you some of the steps.  It provide a 2-SQL normalization technique to very efficiently do that.  If some of your queries are "Summary reports", then it delves into how to make them faster.  Etc.

Even the blind use of `(255)` *for that many columns* has a significant performance burden.

By using appropriate datatypes, plus normalization, will significantly shrink the disk footprint, thereby providing some more performance.

5 columns for the `PRIMARY KEY` -- that is a lot.  Is that the minimal combination of columns that uniquely identify the row?

What will you do with the million rows of output??  Can't you employ MySQL to summarize/condense/whatever the data?  5 minutes is not that unreasonable for locating and shoveling that much data!

`reserved...` -- In the long run, you will probably find out that that kludge is not the best way to do things.

Study the values you are getting from each column to see whether they are worth normalizing.  And to see (for strings) what length makes more sense:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows,
       COUNT(DISTINCT vas_type) AS distinct values,
       MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(vas_type)) AS longest
    FROM tbl;
```

If distinct_values / total_rows > 40%, normalize (you pick the cutoff).
Use `longest`, plus a fudge factor, in `VARCHAR(...)`.
Use `CHARACTER SET latin1` unless there is some need for utf8.